# Perform calculation in TexBox from values in 2 Texboxes binded do sliders

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

I have this code:

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label x:Name="labelMultiplicador" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Multiplicador:" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" />
    <Slider x:Name="sliderMultiplicador" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" SmallChange="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Minimum="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="1" MinHeight="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MinWidth="300" Margin="5" TickPlacement="TopLeft" />
    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxMultiplicador" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Width="50" Text="{Binding ElementName=sliderMultiplicador,Path=Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="1,0,0,0" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MinHeight="30" />

    <Label x:Name="labelMultiplicando" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Multiplicando:" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" />
    <Slider x:Name="sliderMultiplicando" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" SmallChange="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Minimum="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MinWidth="300" Margin="5" Height="1" TickPlacement="TopLeft" />
    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxMultiplicando" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="50" Text="{Binding ElementName=sliderMultiplicando,Path=Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="1,0,0,0" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MinHeight="30" />

    <Label x:Name="labelProduto" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Produto:" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" />
    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxProduto" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Width="50" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="1,0,0,0" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MinHeight="30" />
</Grid>
```

I want to calculate the product (textBoxProduto) using the values from textBoxMultiplicador and textBoxMultiplicando.
I'm new to WPF so this might be a "stupid" question!!!

If i try to calculate the product using the textBoxMultiplicador_TextChanged event, for example, e get a "'System.NullReferenceException'".
What is the best approach in this case?
Thanks

Full example here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8w9t59vjhnqjbb/tabuada.zip?dl=0

Comment: Do both boxes have default values?

If not, Convert.ToInt32(BoxA.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(BoxB.Text) would throw that error as one value is NULL.

Comment: How can i add default values if i have Text="{Binding ElementName=sliderMultiplicando,Path=Value}" in the XAML?

Comment: A lot of ways to do essentially that, more importantly is that the right choice? But if (boxa.Text == "") { a= new int;} a*b would check the value and instantiate if required, but the output would always be 0 (any number times zero, the int's default value) is zero.

Comment: show how you get the `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Attached full example.